# Some files not installed when my package is a nested dependency, even though they do get installed when it's added as a direct dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I have to npm packages, one (say, "parent") depending on the other ("child"). My child package has a number of `.js` files, say `main.js` and `other.js`. The former is listed as `main` in the child's `package.json`.

Both of these should be included in the package. When I inspect the package generated with `npm pack`, it looks fine. When I add the published package as a dependency of the parent and inspect its contents in `parent/node_modules/`, both files are also present, as expected. I then publish parent as a separate package, with the child listed as a dependency.

However, when I then start a new project with the parent as a dependency, and I then install that project's `node_modules/client`, I see `main.js` but not `other.js`! This happens regardless of whether I install it through Yarn or npm. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Well... There was a deeper root cause, so this is probably not going to help anybody, but just in case. The problem was that a different version of this package was getting installed when it was a nested dependency. The reason for this is that the dependency was a prerelease version, specified like `^0.0.1-<commit hash>`. Since the commit hash can start with a number, I had an older version whose commit hash actually started with a higher number, and thus ended up getting installed when the parent specified the child dependency using a caret `^`, but not when I directly added the child dependency.

Specifying the exact version as a dependency in the parent solved the issue.